# Is the :through association the correct way to link a joint table in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have 3 tables named

> > Users table,
> >
> > Messages Table and the
> >
> > Message_users Table

and the Users table will be be used to store users' info while the Messages table will be used to store the messages' sent by users and the Message_users table will store the the message_id and the sender_id(the user who sent the message) and the receiver_id(the user to receive the message)

In the model class of Message, I have this

`class Message < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user, :through :message_user dependent: :destroy
end`

and in the User model, I have this

`class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :messages, :through :message_user, dependent: :destroy
end`

I don't know if this is the correct way to create the linkage between the Message model and the User model

Comment: Do you have a `MessageUser` model (not table, but ActiveRecord model)? Per the docs: '[The has_many :through association] indicates that the declaring model can be matched with zero or more instances of another model by proceeding through a third model.'

Comment: Yes, I do, that has the belongs to user and message

Comment: In that case `has_many :through` will work. However, if you don't need that model for a specific (Ruby) purpose, `has_many` (removing the join table) would be a Rails-y technique. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-association

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your models, it looks like something is a conversation between two users and it has many messages but your "message" model has many "message_users" or something like that. I think the naming is confusing.

Personally, I would have this models:

```
Conversation
  has_many :messages
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users

Message
  belongs_to :conversation
  belongs_to :sender, class_name: 'User'

User
  has_and_belongs_to_many :conversations
  has_many :messages, as: :sender
```

You don't really need to save the receiver_id (it's any user on the conversation that's not the sender of the message). Also you can have more that two users on the same conversation with the same configuration.

Read about HasAndBelongsToMany (it requires you to create a join table "conversations_users" but you don't need a model for it) https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association

I know it does not respect your original tables but they look confusing at least for me.

Comment: Thanks @arieljoud for the info you gave me but if I have to do it your way, it means under or inside the <<conversation table>>, there will be the ID and the SENDER column and inside the <<message table>> will be the ID, CONVERSATION_ID, SENDER and MESSAGE column. I dont know if its going to be structure this way